# How pipelined neural networks are trained?

Tags: neural-network, pipeline, backpropagation, fusion

This is my first question to stackoverflow. I would like to ask something about neural networks and I just need an intuitive explanation. Let's suppose there is a complex neural network architecture (like in the image). There are four vectors G, B, R, P (Green, Blue, Red, Purple) and a scalar number y. The dependencies are something like R = f(G;Weights), P = g(G,B;Weights) and y = h(R,G;Weights). The output is calculated by output = y*R + (1-y)*P. We also define a cost/loss function to calculate an error e. My question is how the error e is backpropagated to fix all the weights of each feedforward network. I just need an intuitive explanation (not the mathematics of gradient descent). I mean, how the error "fixes" the scalar y, which then "fixes" the R and G, but R also "fixes" G ? I'm confused how this kind of architecture works during training. Please help me. Thanx

[Complex Model Architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Zo3t.jpg)

Comment: It's not entirely clear what your input data is - do I understand it properly from your formulas that only G and B are inputs, with R,P,y,output and e being calculation steps fully determined by the values of GB and weights?

Comment: This is totally correct. The inputs are G and B. The loss function is depended only on output. So my question is how the error from the loss function is backpropagated to train each network independently. Also, each network should be trained independently nonetheless or is it ok to train the model as a whole ?